# font from psd file for web page

Tags: fonts, psd

I recently took on a project to build a webpage. I am an experienced developer but never worked with coding a psd file into a webpage.

Now, the psd file uses a specific font, which I do not have probably, as I can see it in grey and [ ] at the bottom of the fonts list.

Sorry for the naive question, but what am I supposed to do from the client's point of view? Should I have that font? Should I buy it? Can I extract it from the psd file?
And then, does it come into the web-page as @font-face?

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with custom fonts in a situation like this is not technical but legal and comes down to the right of distribution.

If you are not allowed to distribute the font, then you can't put it on a website, as users will have to download and install it (constituting distribution).

You will have to explain this to your client (or talk it over with the designer first if possible).